# How to create a custom page in ActiveAdmin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.0, PSQL 9.3

In the ActiveAdmin documentation there is the example:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "My Page" do
  content do
    para "Hello World"
  end
end
```

Where do I put this code? The documentation says:

> In the above example, a new page will be created at /admin/my_page
>   with the title “My Page” and the content of “Hello World”.

This implies that such a file would be created automatically somehow? Nevertheless, I created a file named `import.rb` under app/admin and the Import item in the menu does appear. However, I am not able to use HTML, as this file is .rb and not .erb. I suppose, in order to be able to use html, I need to create a partial and den render it within the `content` method. But when I look under `app/views` there is not `admin` folder (only `layouts`). Does this mean I need to create the folder `admin` under `app/views`? If yes, where should I put my partial - directly under `app/views/admin` or under a new folder `app/views/admin/import`?

I am sorry for the menu questions, but the documentation of ActiveAdmin is pretty modest. I would really appreciate if someone could provide a more details explanation of the steps needed for creating and adding content to a new page in ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What the documentation meant was that if you create a new custom page `app/admin/my_page.rb`, this page will be available in the URL `/admin/my_page` (if you are using the default ActiveAdmin configuration).

Regarding rendering of an ERB or HAML partials for your `my_page.rb`, you can do it this way:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "My Page" do
  content do
    render :partial => 'about'
  end
end
```

This will look under the directory `app/views/admin/my_page/`. If the directories do not exist, create them. Also, you can still specify other directories by referencing the full template path (e.g. `shared/sections/about`) like you would for a non-ActiveAdmin controller.

Comment: And from where does we access this page?

Comment: @NidhinSG: "this page will be available in the URL /admin/my_page" :-)